# Rails Routes Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a really simple app I've built using RoR but I'm stuck modifying my routes.

It's basically a site which lists user information - I need to change the url from:

```
mydomain.com/users/user-1
```

to

```
mydomain.com/user-1
```

Update..

I've managed to route the above request using:

```
match "/:id", :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"
```

But what I really need to do is change the route for all requests to `/users/#` to `/`

Although my route is working, all my links to show a user still point to:

```
/users/user-#
```

--- Update ---

The routing for /user-id is now working perfectly however, I'm struggling with the rest of the routing now.

I can now navigate to http://localhost/user-1

However, I basically need to remove the /user/ part completely. When I'm editing / updating a page, I end up with it going to:

/users/user-1/edit

All works fine but it then redirects to"

/users/user-1/

I really need both of these to redirect to

http://localhost/user-1/edit

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
resources :users, :path => '/'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Using that gives me an error: "Couldn't find User without an ID"

Comment: Do you get the output you want from rake routes? Also, can you see how the route is being parsed in the log? Is there an :id set in the params hash?

Comment: Hi, rake routes looks pretty good I think. The output from development.log is as follows: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Page without an ID):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:96:in `find_user'

As you will see, I've moved from users to pages which belong to users. Sorry for any confusion and thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I think the issue is with find_user in the pages controller which I've removed and the pages load successfully. Just got to work through what the impact is - think I will have an issue passing the id across

Comment: If you nested pages under users, you will need to load the user with :user_id rather than :id.

Comment: Hi, removing find_user from controller made it work but I now I can't add a new page for a user. I think I already have user_id as below      def find_user
        if params[:user_id]
          @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        else
          @page = Page.find(params[:id])
          @user = @page.user
        end
        unless current_user == @user
          redirect_to @user, :alert => "Are you logged in properly? You are not allowed to create or change someone else's subdomain."
        end
      end  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your routes

```
match "/:id", :to => "users#show"
```

There is some side effects so be ready

to rewrite your routes you should specify its name:

```
match "/:id", :to => "users#show", :as => :user
```

or, as @Whirlwin pointed, better to use just GET request as default

```
get "/:id", :to => "users#show", :as => :user
```

So now you can call:

```
user_path(@user)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Let me give that a try later (when I'm not in trouble with the mrs for playing with the Internet again)...

Comment: Hi. I seem to get a routing error caused by changing the link in index from user to user_path(@user)...    Says, no route matches. Sorry if I'm being dumb, I just cannot get my head around routes...

Comment: also you can leave `@user` instead of `user_path(@user)` because it is synonyms

Comment: Hi again. This is now working fine but I have an issue with updating user records. When I edit / update, the changes are not made. Not sure what I need to do in the routes file to sort this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `get ":id" => "users#show"` will be much the same except you only allow HTTP GET. Hope this works.

Comment: yep, it would more clever approach

Comment: Yeah, that worked thanks. Have edited my question a little because I don't think I was very clear. Is it possible to route all requests to /users/user-id to the root path?

Comment: you should specify `as` option for your route